# How to store Object in Ceph Object Store

Tags: java, ceph

I have deployed a Ceph cluster over 3 nodes and have created `msd` and `rgw`. I have 3 machines named ceph1, ceph2 and ceph3.

- ceph1 runs osd, mon, mds and rwg
- ceph2 runs osd
- ceph3 runs osd

I have created a user with `radosgw-admin user create` command.

Now I want to access the ceph cluster using swift api and create a  container. For that I wrote following java code :

```
import org.javaswift.joss.client.factory.AccountConfig;
import org.javaswift.joss.client.factory.AccountFactory;
import org.javaswift.joss.client.factory.AuthenticationMethod;
import org.javaswift.joss.model.Account;
import org.javaswift.joss.model.Container;
import org.javaswift.joss.model.StoredObject;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String username = "sahoo";
    String password = "IM8K5GAQIXHFRAKYS761";
    String authUrl  = "http://ceph1:7480/";

    AccountConfig config = new AccountConfig();
    config.setUsername(username);
    config.setPassword(password);
    config.setAuthUrl(authUrl);
    config.setAuthenticationMethod(AuthenticationMethod.BASIC);

    Account account = new AccountFactory(config).createAccount();
    Container container = account.getContainer("container-name");
    container.create();
}
}
```

But while running the code I get following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.identity.BasicAuthenticationCommandImpl.getReturnObject(BasicAuthenticationCommandImpl.java:35)
at org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.identity.BasicAuthenticationCommandImpl.getReturnObject(BasicAuthenticationCommandImpl.java:18)
at org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.core.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:51)
at org.javaswift.joss.client.impl.ClientImpl.createAccount(ClientImpl.java:97)
at org.javaswift.joss.client.impl.ClientImpl.createAccount(ClientImpl.java:27)
at org.javaswift.joss.client.core.AbstractClient.authenticate(AbstractClient.java:35)
at org.javaswift.joss.client.factory.AccountFactory.createAccount(AccountFactory.java:30)
at Example.main(Example.java:24)
```

Can any one help me out with why I am getting the exception and exactly what we need to pass to `config.setAuthUrl()`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create subuser to use swift API.

`sudo radosgw-admin subuser create radosgw-admin subuser create --uid={uid} --subuser={uid} --access=[ read | write | readwrite | full ]`

REF: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/giant/radosgw/admin/

> To create a subuser (Swift interface) for the user, you must specify the user ID (--uid={username}), a subuser ID and the access level for the subuser.

Then, we need to pass the URL of Ceph RGW to `config.setAuthUrl()`. It would be better to test with `swift` command quickly.

For example, if you could confirm to create a container by this command:

`# swift -V 1.0 -A http://ceph.example.com/auth/v1 -U foo:swift -K testsecret post test-container`

Then, you can specify following variables:

- config.setUsername() ... `foo:swift`
- config.setPassword() ... `testsecret`
- config.setAuthUrl()  ... `http://ceph.example.com/auth/v1`